# Visual Studio Android solution stops building upon hitting C# version conflict when using MSBuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

The solution builds fine in Visual Studio 2017.

MSBuild will produce the following warning:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (2106, 5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved. These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

A couple line will show up after the warning, but from there it halts and doesn't progress at all.

The actual reference conflict is here:

> There was a conflict between "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". (TaskId:123)
>   4>      "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not. (TaskId:123)
>   4>      References which depend on "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll]. (TaskId:123)
>   4>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll (TaskId:123)
>   4>            Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll". (TaskId:123)
>   4>              Microsoft.CSharp (TaskId:123)
>   4>      References which depend on "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" []. (TaskId:123)
>   4>          C:\Users\laniganr.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\10.0.3\lib\netstandard1.3\Newtonsoft.Json.dll (TaskId:123)

A couple other lines will show up right after the error, but never progresses past this point.

Said lines:

> _XamarinAndroidBuildAarRestore:
>     Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj\ReleaseNuget\XbdMerge\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Bas
>     ement.dll.stamp
>     Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj\ReleaseNuget\XbdMerge\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tas
>     ks.dll.stamp
>     Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj\ReleaseNuget\XbdMerge\Xamarin.Firebase.Common.dll.st
>     amp
>     Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj\ReleaseNuget\XbdMerge\Xamarin.Firebase.Iid.dll.stamp
>     Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj\ReleaseNuget\XbdMerge\Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.dll
>     .stamp
>   _ResolveLibraryProjectImports:
>   Skipping target "_ResolveLibraryProjectImports" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files
>   .
>   _BuildLibraryImportsCache:
>   Skipping target "_BuildLibraryImportsCache" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Visual Studio Android solution stops building upon hitting C# version conflict when using MSBuild

That because there is an explicit reference to `Microsoft.CSharp 2.0.5.0` in the `Xamarin.Android` project when there is a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp 4.3.0.0` in the `netstandard` library project from a library `newtonsoft.json 10.0.3`.

In the build log, you can find your project referencing the package `newtonsoft.json` in following message:

> C:\Users\xxxxx\packages\newtonsoft.json\10.0.3\lib\netstandard1.3\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>   (TaskId:123)

Then check the dependence of the package `newtonsoft.json\10.0.3\lib\netstandard1.3`:

[image]

To resolve this issue, you can try to update `Newtonsoft.Json` to the version `11.0.1` and above. This is because this version of `Newtonsoft.Json` package for `netstandard 2.0` has no dependency to `Microsoft.CSharp`.

Alternatively, you can remove the `Microsoft.CSharp 2.0.5` and allow the one from Nuget to be used.

You can refer to the similar thread [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1261) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569028/found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-dependent-assembly-that-c) for some more details.

Hope this helps.